# Coupling with other analysis software?

Tags: openmdao

I'm a newbie in multidisciplinary design optimization and I want to know is there any way to couple commercial analysis systems such as ANSYS, ABAQUS... with OpenMDAO to automate the aircraft design process. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely run an external commercial code through OpenMDAO by using an ExternalCodeComp.

http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/components/external_code_comp.html

It isn't a trivial task, but I don't think it is conceptually difficult either. You will need to write data to an input file that your external code reads, and then parse the output files to pull data back into OpenMDAO. Unless someone has already written a wrapper for the code you are using, you'll have to do that on your own.